# How do I use php to hit a web service I created using gSoap and C++?

Tags: php, soap, gsoap

I have created the gSOAP Calculator Service example found at: http://www.genivia.com/Products/gsoap/demos/index.html

I have my web service running as a deamon on my Solaris box.

Now I'm trying to use a php page to hit this new web service.  I have been looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php, and have tried to make an example, but have had no luck.  Can someone please point me to an example of doing this? or show me the code for doing it?

I have spent two days looking at web sites and trying different things and am running out of time on my project.  Thank you so much for your help.

fyi: I have my apache server set to port 7000.

```
<?php

function customError($errno, $errstr)
{
  echo "<b>Error: </b> [$errno] $errstr";
}

set_error_handler("customError");

define("SOAP_ENCODED", 1);
define("SOAP_RPC", 1);

$options = array(
 'compression'=>true,
 'exceptions'=>false,
 'trace'=>true,
 'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,
 'style'=> SOAP_RPC,
 'location'=> "http://localhost:7000",
 'uri' => "urn:calc"
);

echo "1";

$client = @new SoapClient(null, $options);

echo "2";

$args = array(2, 3);

$ret = $client->__soapCall("add", $args);

echo "3";

if (is_soap_fault($ret))
{
  echo 'fault : ';
  var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
  var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());

}
else
{
echo 'success : ';
  print '__'.$ret.'__';
}

$client->ns__allAllowed();
?>
```

The web page does not return any errors.

Michael

Comment: Post the code you've tried. And any errors you're getting when you run it.

Comment: Put this at the top of the script: `error_reporting(-1);` and remove the `@` here: `$client = @new SoapClient(null, $options);` and try the page again to see if there is any errors. Also is anything echoing?

Comment: I did that.  No difference.  Page comes back blank.  Even when I view source.

Comment: Create a new php page and put this into it `<?php phpinfo();` and run it in the browser. Is it also returning a blank page?

Comment: It should not, since most of my site is written in PHP and it all works.

Comment: anything clues in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`?

Comment: No new items in the log.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
```

Some things to check:

- Include Unicode Signature (BOM) is **off** in your editor
- No white space after `?>` (You should just remove it)
- Run the script in cli `php /path/myscript.php`

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial you mentioned written that Calc web service generates [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSDL). WSDL is a file that describes all methods and types of web service. Keeping this in mind you can create SOAP client in PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.mysite.com/calc.wsdl',
                          array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true));
```

Then you can call any method provided by Web service:

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('http://www.mysite.com/calc.wsdl',
                          array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true));

    $result = $client->methodName($param1, $param2);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}

var_dump($result);
```

If some error will occur you'll catch it in try/catch block.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but I still get a blank page.  I can see my calc application in a terminal spitting out "Socket connection..." info.  If I run the calc from the command line like a cgi script, it works fine.

Comment: Any other output on this page if some `echo` added before or after try and catch? If not it seems to be the problem with PHP. SOAP extension needs to be compiled with libxml and curl extensions and they must be turned on. OpenSSL is needed too if you use HTTPS connection. Please check you phpinfo() for this libs and SOAP Extension (if it's enabled you should see SOAP section).

Comment: The only thing I see when I run phpinfo is in a section called "Configure Command" and at the end of that command I see "--enable-soap-shared".  Is this right?  If not how do I fix it?

Comment: I also see a section called "libxml Version" which is set to "2.6.23"

Comment: @TheBigOnion: no, that's not right. I think that your SOAP extension is disabled. Check your php.ini (and conf.d directory) for `extension=soap.so`. Make sure that it has no ";" symbol in the beginning of this line. If there are no such line, you should get one. After uncommenting this line you must restart web-server.

Comment: I cannot find the php.ini file nor the conf.d directory.

Comment: @TheBigOnion: Use phpinfo() to find php.ini used by your script.